# Unable to read from external text file

Tags: c++

I've got a dynamically allocated array of a struct type (let's call it structtype), and I was trying to read to it from an external text file. structtype looks something like this:

```
{
    char itemName[15];
    char status;
    int itemAmt;
    char tried;
    char desc[130];
    int rating;
}
```

And the text file looks something like this:

```
SomeName: y | 3 | Hello Hello | y | 9
```

in that exact format. I am trying to read from said text file using this code:

```
void games::LoadFrom(){ // Loads games from the file into array (AllItems)
        ifstream file_in;
        structtype temparray[15] = {};
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) // Empties out AllItems
                AllItems[i] = {};
        file_in.open("items.txt");
        int i = 0; // Counter
        if (file_in){
                while (!file_in.eof() && i < 15){ // Checks if its the end of the file, or if its the max amount I can store
                        file_in.get(temparray[i].itemName, 15, ':');
                        file_in.ignore(100, '|');

                        file_in >> temparray[i].status;
                        file_in.ignore(100, '|');
                        AllItems[i].status = temparray[i].status;

                        file_in >> temparray[i].itemAmt;
                        file_in.ignore(100, '|');
                        AllItems[i].playerAmt = temparray[i].itemAmt;

                        file_in.get(temparray[i].desc, 131, '|');            // All of this reads in a game from the file, and stores it in the AllItems array
                        file_in.ignore(100, '|');

                        file_in >> temparray[i].tried;
                        file_in.ignore(100, '|');
                        AllItems[i].tried = temparray[i].tried;

                        file_in >> temparray[i].rating;
                        file_in.ignore(100, '\n');
                        AllItems[i].rating = temparray[i].rating;

                        ++i;

                        file_in.get(temparray[i].itemName, 15, ':');
                        file_in.ignore(100, ':');
                }
                cout << AllItems[0].itemAmt;

        }
        cout << AllItems[0].itemAmt;
        file_in.close();

    }
```

My problem is that it doesn't read anything in, and instead leaves everything in the struct object at its zero equivalent.

### Important

To keep in mind: AllItems is a dynamically allocated array, and I was unable to read stuff to it directly, instead I made a separate statically allocated array called temparray, which is strictly for transferring info to AllItems.

When the loop runs, it runs once, and then exits, even though the text file has about 10 items. How can I actually read items in?

Comment: The problem is that your reading code does not correspond to your file format. For example you just have just added `file_in.ignore(100, '|');` after every read even when it's not appropriate. It seems you think it is some kind of magic spell.

Comment: I guess I dont fully understand what a .ignore() is. would you mind helping me figure it out?

Comment: `ignore` reads and discards until either the specified character is found or until the number of characters indicated have been read . The main problem is that you are using it when it isn't needed or with the wrong character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what your code should look like. I've ignored the `AllItems` and `AllGames` arrays, and just concentrated on `temparray`

```
    while (!file_in.eof() && i < 15){ // Checks if its the end of the file, or if its the max amount I can store
        file_in.getline(temparray[i].itemName, 15, ':');
        file_in >> temparray[i].status;
        file_in.ignore(100, '|');
        file_in >> temparray[i].itemAmt;
        file_in.ignore(100, '|');
        file_in.getline(temparray[i].desc, 130, '|');            // All of this reads in a game from the file, and stores it in the AllItems array
        file_in >> temparray[i].tried;
        file_in.ignore(100, '|');
        file_in >> temparray[i].rating;
        file_in.ignore(100, '\n');
        ++i;
    }
```

Main differences with your code - I've used `getline` not `get` so the terminating character (`':'` or `'|'`) is read and discarded. I've only used `ignore` after a formatted extraction (i.e. after `>>`) when it is necessary to discard the trailing separator.

When you are writing this kind of code you have to understand *in detail* what each reading function does, and how that effects the file format you have. It's not good enough to throw together a bunch of code that is roughly the same as your file format, it has to be exactly right.

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments below the above code has a problem which is how it handles end of file. It makes the common error of testing for `eof` before a read, not afterwards. Here's a version that tests correctly.

```
   while (i < 15 &&
        file_in.getline(temparray[i].itemName, 15, ':') &&
        file_in >> temparray[i].status &&
        file_in.ignore(100, '|') &&
        file_in >> temparray[i].itemAmt &&
        file_in.ignore(100, '|') &&
        file_in.getline(temparray[i].desc, 130, '|') &&
        file_in >> temparray[i].tried &&
        file_in.ignore(100, '|') &&
        file_in >> temparray[i].rating &&
        file_in.ignore(100, '\n'))
    {
        ++i;
    }
```

In this version only if all reads succeed does the while loop get executed and `i` get incremented.

A read could fail either because of end of file, or because of a format error. If you need to distinguish those two cases you need some more sophisticated code.

Comment: So I have a question, my professor said that in order for a .eof() to work, you first have to try to read something in, which is why I have the extra cin at the bottom, do i not need that?

Comment: Your professor is correct, but your solution is not correct.

Comment: I'll update my answer.

Comment: In good C++ code, the `if` is around the `getline` calls, and `eof` is not used at all.

Comment: Also, if I were to want to copy over the desc, and the name to AllItems how would I do that? I tried strcpy, but I guess i did it wrong, or it just doesn't work.

Comment: BTW srry bout the rogue AllGames array, thats from the assignment, I changed all of them to AllItems for simplicity I guess I missed this one.

Comment: `strcpy` is the correct way to copy a string. So maybe you didn't do it right.

Comment: would it look something like: strcpy(AllItems[i].itemName, temparray[i].itemName) ?

Comment: @MishaShepsis Looks good to me.

Comment: One last thing, what library do I need to #include for strcpy?

Comment: `#include <cstring>`